gpkg filename to add PostGIS table field
Is there a way in ogr2ogr to add gpkg filename to a PostGIS table existing field (filename)? during append?
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host='ip' port='port' user='user' dbname='db' password='pass'" "file.gpkg" -append -nln table


You can use the -sql flag to create arbitrary columns in the output.
I've not got a PostGIS handy so I'm going to add to an existant table.gpkg file. It has 5 rows and the file column is all "nc1":
$ ogrinfo -so -al table.gpkg 
INFO: Open of `table.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: table
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 5
...
$ ogrinfo -al table.gpkg | grep file
file: String (0.0)
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1

Now I want to append nc2.gpkg and set file to "nc2":
$ ogr2ogr -sql "select *,'nc2' as file from 'nc2'" -append table.gpkg nc2.gpkg -nln table

(Note that the 'nc2' in 'nc2' as file is the string value (and can be anything) and the second one (in from 'nc2') is the layer name derived from nc2.gpkg)
Now table.gpkg has 10 rows, five are nc1 and five are nc2:
$ ogrinfo -al table.gpkg | grep file
file: String (0.0)
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc1
  file (String) = nc2
  file (String) = nc2
  file (String) = nc2
  file (String) = nc2
  file (String) = nc2

This should also work with PostGIS with some adjustment of the DSN specifications. Test on a sacrificial table first in case you accidentally forget to append...

I have a loop for multiple gpkgs to be loaded into the same postgis table, what sould I add to the -sql statement to make it work?
set val=%%f
set val2=%%~nxf the second one is the filename with extension.

ignore me, the sql requires the layer name (no extension) not the file name, so in my case val2=%%~nf

I had a feeling looping might have been your next question and glad you solved it without me having to work out how to do it in what looks like Windows shell instead of Linux bash :)
